# Unresolved Reference in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting

> Unresolved Reference 'palindrome'

It is a program to check if numbers are palindrome or not.

```
import sys  
n = int(input("Enter number of numbers : "))  
l = list()  
for x in range(0, n):  
    l.append(input("Enter number {0}".format(x+1)))  
for x in range(0, n):  
    b = palindrome(l.index(x))  #unresolved reference here  
    if b:  
        print(l.index(x))  


def palindrome(j):  
    t = j  
    f = 0  
    while t > 0:  
        m = t % 10  
        f = (f*10)+m  
    if f == j:  
        return True  
    else:  
        return False
```

Comment: Define `palindrome` before you call it. Just move it up.

Answer (score 3):

`palindrome` doesn't get defined until the program reaches the `def` line. Try moving it up above your main code.

```
def palindrome(j):
    t = j
    f = 0
    while t > 0:
        m = t % 10
        f = (f*10)+m
    if f == j:
        return True
    else:
        return False

n = int(input("Enter number of numbers : "))
l = list()
for x in range(0, n):
    l.append(input("Enter number {0}".format(x+1)))
for x in range(0, n):
    b = palindrome(l.index(x))  #unresolved reference here
    if b:
        print(l.index(x))
```

Comment: In the function you can replace `if ... else ...` with `return f == j`